# Plastic SCM - Ignore directory on repository on initial sync to new workspace

Tags: git

I'm unsure if this is the right place to ask but I'm working remotely and started a new workspace and want to sync the repository.  One of the folders has a few gigs of files in it and I want to ignore this folder completely to save me downloading the whole thing.  Is this possible?

I can see that I can ignore files from my workspace end so it doesn't commit them but is there a way to do it on sync so I don't have to download everything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the intems to the **"cloaked list"**.

Cloaked items are items that the update operation won't download by default from the repository to the workspace. This is convenient in some scenarios, for instance when there are big files in the repository that are updated often, but you don't really work with them, so you prefer to skip downloading those cloaked files every time you switch the workspace to a different branch or do an update of the workspace.

More info at: 
[PlasticSCM documentation](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gui/plastic-scm-version-control-gui-guide.shtml)